# Updating Listview after adding/removing item

Tags: c#, listview, windows-store-apps

How can I refresh ListView after adding item to collection in Windows Store app? Adding items to list works fine, but Listview doesn't refresh. I was trying to implement *INotifyCollectionChanged*, but what exactly should I do to make it work?

edit: XAML file

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="437" Margin="10,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="593" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="#FF5D5D5D">
        <ListView.DataContext>
            <Model:School/>
        </ListView.DataContext>
    </ListView>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Command="{Binding AddCommand, Mode=OneWay}">
        <Button.DataContext>
            <Model:School/>
        </Button.DataContext>            
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

C# code:

```
class School
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _persons = new ObservableCollection<string>()
    {
        "Name1", "Name2", "Name3"
    };

    public ObservableCollection<string> Persons
    {
        get { return _persons; }
    }

    private ICommand _addCommand;
    public ICommand AddCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return this._addCommand ??
                   (this._addCommand = new RelayCommand(Add));
        }
    }

    private void Add()
    {
        this._persons.Add("Name");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add *INotifyCollectionChanged* when you are using *ObservableCollection* - it already implements needed interfaces.

Your code should work, though there may be some other problems:

- check if the *DataContext* of your ListView (its parent in this case) is properly set - it should be set, so that 'ListView would find' *Persons* property,
- also check if the *ItemTemplate* is properly set - example:

  ```
  <ListView Name="myList" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Surname}"/>
            </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
  ```
- in your case there is no need that your ListView's *ItemsSource* uses *TwoWay* binding - you are not defining a setter ofr the property *Persons*.

EDIT:

After your edit, I can see where is the problem - you are setting separate *DataContext* for your *ListView* and *Button* - the button is adding to **its own** collection - different than *ListView* is bound to. Take a short test - set the *DataContext* of both to same staticresource:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Model:School x:Key="mySchool"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,120,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" Background="#FF5D5D5D"
              DataContext="{StaticResource mySchool}"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,64,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Command="{Binding AddCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
            DataContext="{StaticResource mySchool}">
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I think DataContext is set properly, when I add objects to list in its declaration, I can see them displayed. Adding items to list works too, I checked it in debugger. I edited my code in the previous post, that's basically all we need to make it work, but for some reason it doesn't. I have no idea what's wrong or maybe I just don't understand something?

Comment: @MrCrow I've added an edit. I think it should help to solve the problem.

Comment: @MrCrow Note only that there are other probably better ways of setting DataContext, you can set it for the whole page, for grid, in code or in xaml. Just pay attention not to create few models when you need one. Good luck.

Comment: I see, but here's another question: what if I want to have my list displayed on multiple pages? Is possible to declare context and share it between them?

Comment: @MrCrow That's not a problem - you can declare your model app-wide as a static resource, or as variable in app class, then on each page you can set datacontext in constructor, or in xaml. There are multiple ways to do it.